# Getting Sprockets::FileNotFound for assets loaded from https://rails-assets.org/

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I get Sprockets::FileNotFound for all the assets I have included from the rails-assets.org even though I have followed the instructions on rails-assets.org (see below and did also a bundle install). The Rails.application.config.assets.paths shows the gem files as asset paths. Ay idea what else is missing?

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'https://rails-assets.org'
...
#gems from rails-assets.org. These are gems created from Bower's repository
gem 'rails-assets-angular'
gem 'rails-assets-angular-ui-router'
gem 'rails-assets-d3'
gem 'rails-assets-elasticsearch'
gem 'rails-assets-lodash'
gem 'rails-assets-nvd3'
gem 'rails-assets-restangular'
gem 'rails-assets-angular-bootstrap'
```

**application.js:**

```
...
//From rails-assets.org
//= require angular
//= require angular-ui-router
//= require d3
//= require elasticsearch
//= require lodash
//= require nvd3
//= require restangular
//= require angular-bootstrap

//= require kamaji_main
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your server (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, then `rails s`).